# Define a predicate in prolog

Tags: prolog

Define `sublist(Xs, Ys)`:
this holds when `Xs` is a list containing some of the elements of `Ys`, in the same order they appear in the list `Ys`. For example, `sublist(X,[a,b,c])` should have the eight solutions `X=[]; X=[c]; X=[b]; X=[b,c]; X=[a]; X=[a,c]; X=[a,b];` and `X=[a,b,c].`

My solution is like this:

```
sublist([],[]).
sublist([],[_|_]).
sublist([X|Xs],[Y|Ys]):- (
X=Y->sublist(Xs,Ys);
sublist([X|Xs],Ys)
).
```

However, it only outputs:

```
X = [] ;
X = [a] ;
X = [a, b] ;
X = [a, b, c].
```

what's wrong with my solution?

Comment: You are using if-then-else, so it never tries the second conjunct. This would have been obvious if you had tried to trace. (The call `X=Y` will always succeed when either variable is uninstantiated).

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, the problem is in your if statement. You should rewrite your program like this:

```
sublist([],[]).
sublist([],[_|_]).
sublist([X|Xs],[X|Ys]):-
    sublist(Xs,Ys).

sublist([X|Xs],[_|Ys]):-
    sublist([X|Xs],Ys).

?- sublist(A,[a,b,c]).
A = []
A = [a]
A = [a, b]
A = [a, b, c]
A = [a, c]
A = [b]
A = [b, c]
A = [c]
```

BTW, `sublist/2` is a built in predicate in SWI. You can look at that implementation wich is (taken from [here](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/7c97611b9c6df0e749094de51313a7a419dd7989/src/Tests/core/test_d_break.pl)):

```
sublist(L, L).
sublist(Sub, [H|T]) :-
    sublist_(T, H, Sub).

sublist_(Sub, _, Sub).
sublist_([H|T], _, Sub) :-
    sublist_(T, H, Sub).
sublist_([H|T], X, [X|Sub]) :-
    sublist_(T, H, Sub).
```